# I want to be able to display data from one site in my wordpress multisite network on another site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api, multisite

I want to be able to display data from one site in my wordpress multisite network on another site. Please what is the easiest way to acheive this?

Are there any exixting plugin to do this?

Been looking for answers, never seem to find one.

Comment: If you want to do it from within your own coding: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/

Answer (score 0):

You can create API endpoints and serve the data that way.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/